# Running Spark-Task with SparkLauncher

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my local scala-app I want to start a Spark-task at my cluster. The task-class is my.spark.SparkRunner and it´s contained in a jar which is in the HDFS, and this is what I´ve configured in my local program:

```
val spark = new SparkLauncher()
  //.setSparkHome("C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
  .setVerbose(true)
  .setAppResource("hdfs://192.168.10.183:8020/spark/myjar.jar")
  .setMainClass("my.spark.SparkRunner")
  .setMaster("spark://192.168.10.183:7077")
  //.setMaster("192.168.10.183:7077")
  .launch();

spark.waitFor();
```

It throws no error but returns immediately and doesn´t start the task. What am I doing wrong? Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just added a thread which checks the state of launcher, thats it ...

```
val spark = new SparkLauncher()
  //.setSparkHome("C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
  .setVerbose(true)
  .setAppResource("hdfs://192.168.10.183:8020/spark/myjar.jar")
  .setMainClass("my.spark.SparkRunner")
  .setMaster("spark://192.168.10.183:7077")
  //.setMaster("192.168.10.183:7077")
  .startApplication();

while (spark.getState.toString != "FINISHED") {

    println (spark.getState)

    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```